# Getting errors while using 'got' package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, dependencies

I am using 'got' version '11.8.3' and I am getting below error.

*/app/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:696
throw new TypeError('The payload has been already provided');
^
TypeError: The payload has been already provided
at Request.onLockedWrite (/app/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:696:19)
at PassThrough. (node:internal/streams/pipeline:323:31)*

Hence I tried to upgrade 'got' to latest (12.0.3). But after this I am getting below error:

*/app/server/lib/my-api.js:8
const got_1 = __importDefault(require("got"));
^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /app/node_modules/got/dist/source/index.js from /app/server/lib/my-api.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /app/server/lib/my-api.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.*

However, I am using this statement in my .ts file.
`import got from 'got'`

Can you suggest on eliminating these errors

Comment: Your TypeScript settings are converting `import` to `require` and the `got` package is not compatible with it

Comment: In that case, is there any way we can eliminate the first error that's coming with got '11.8.3' version ('The payload has been already provided')

Answer (score 3):

here's a fix.

first

```
npm i fix-esm
```

then you can import got package like this

```
const got = require("fix-esm").require("got");
```

Next install got version 10.0.0

```
npm i got@10.0.0
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: TypeError: got is not a function